# To hide the panel based on text

Tags: javascript

The below mentioned script working properly (1) but if i put elseif condition its not working(2)

how can i use elseif condition

Step 1

```
function cl_Indexchange(sender, eventArgs) {
        var pnl = document.getElementById("pnlSchedule");
        var item = eventArgs.get_item();
        if (item.get_text() == "Call Back Later (CBL)") {
            pnl.style.display = "block";
        } else

         {
            pnl.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

Step 2

```
function cl_Indexchange(sender, eventArgs) {
            var pnl = document.getElementById("pnlSchedule");
            var item = eventArgs.get_item();
            if (item.get_text() == "Call Back Later (CBL)") {
                 pnl.style.display = "block";
            } else
               (item.get_text() == "Call Back After Explanation (CBE)") {
                    pnl.style.display = "block";
            }
            elseif
              (item.get_text() == "Call Back After Explanation (CBE)") {
                  pnl.style.display = "block";
            }elseif
            {
                 pnl.style.display = "none";
            }
     }
```

Comment: `elseif` isn't a _thing_ in JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have incorrectly structured `if-else` here. `else` would always come as last statement for `if` and in between `else if`  will come and you need to provide **space** between `else` and `if` as below:

```
if (item.get_text() == "Call Back Later (CBL)") {
   pnl.style.display = "block";
} 
else if(item.get_text() == "Call Back After Explanation (CBE)") {
   pnl.style.display = "block";
}
else
{
   pnl.style.display = "none";
}
```

Also you can merge `else if` part since it does same thing and you can have single `if` and `else`  statement:

```
if (item.get_text() == "Call Back Later (CBL)" || item.get_text() == "Call Back After Explanation (CBE)") {
   pnl.style.display = "block";
} 
else
{
   pnl.style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `if-else` structure is not proper. try this

```
function cl_Indexchange(sender, eventArgs) {
    var pnl = document.getElementById("pnlSchedule");
    var item = eventArgs.get_item();
    if (item.get_text() == "Call Back Later (CBL)") {
        pnl.style.display = "block";
    } else if (item.get_text() == "Call Back After Explanation (CBE)") {
        pnl.style.display = "block";
    }  else {
        pnl.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```